# Get value from Metrics in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, metrics

I'm using ASP.NET Core 6 and have a reference to [App Metrics](https://www.app-metrics.io/getting-started/).

With the following code, I'm adding a new counter-metrics on the API and it is working properly when I'm looking at `/metrics-text` endpoint.

```cs
public static class MetricsRegistry
{
    public static CounterOptions SampleValue => new CounterOptions
    {
        Name = "SampleValue",
        Context = "Application",
        MeasurementUnit = Unit.Requests
    };
}
```

Then the increment the Metrics:

```cs
_metrics.Measure.Counter.Increment(MetricsRegistry.SampleValue);
```

But I would to have access to that metrics on runtime. I tried to use `Snapshot` but it is not working.

```cs
var value = _metrics.Snapshot.GetCounterValue("Application", MetricsRegistry.SampleValue.Name);
```

Is there any way to get the value on runtime?

Comment: Seems like an AppMetrics specific question no? Where's the ASP.NET in this?

Comment: Yes sure, but App Metrics provides a set of packages designed for ASP.NET Core.